# JQuery Отметка чекбоксов

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Добрый день :)
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема.
Есть таблица с чекбоксами и главный чекбокс для выделения всех чекбоксов.

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th> <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" /></th>
            .....
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody> 
    <tr>
        <td> <input type="checkbox" id="ch14" class="check"   name="dump[]" value="14" onclick="calculate(14,10.00);"/> </td>
        ....
    </tr>
```

И такой JS собственно:

```
function calculate(id,p) {
    if($("#ch"+id).prop("checked")) {
        price = parseFloat($("#price").html()) + p;
    }
    else {
        price = parseFloat($("#price").html()) - p;
    }

    $("#price").html(price);
}

$("#checkAll").change(function(){ 
    if($(this).attr("checked")){ 
        $("input:checkbox").attr("checked",false); 
        $("#price").html(0);
    }
    else {
        $("input:checkbox").attr("checked",true);
        $("#price").html(50);
    }
});
```

Первый раз отмечается / снимается всё отлично. А второй раз уже чекбоксы не отмечаются. В чем может быть проблема ?

Answer (score 8):

```
$('#checkAll').on('change', function() {
    $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
    $("#price").html(this.checked ? 0 : 50);
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/coder13/MyaWZ/

Comment: помогло решение и мне спасибо +1

Answer (score 1):

Читайте также: [jQuery checkbox](http://wdtime.ru/jquery/jquery-checkbox)