# Проблема с CheckBox и Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Подскажите пожалуйта, как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на главный CheckBox активировались все остальные простые?

Comment: а как главный отличается от остальных?

Comment: @Semen  Savenko, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос уже поднимался здесь, пользуйтесь поиском.

[JQuery Отметка чекбоксов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/243522/checkbox-jquery-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=243525#243525)

Answer (score -1):

На главный checkbox пропиши onchange="Check_boxes()" и внутри него сделай проверку если он установлен, тогда для остальных поставить checked = 1.